# Get text of input in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, end-to-end

How do I get text of input and use it in my test? The code bellow returs an Protractor Object and not the text.

```js
var typed  = element(by.css(css + ' input')).getAttribute('value');
if (typed === 'something') { // doSomething() }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to getText on an input in protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310442/how-to-gettext-on-an-input-in-protractor)

Comment: its not necessarily a duplicate but it is very easy, to find out that you need to resolve promises with a then callback, with a simple google search or search on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The function [getAttribute](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) returns a promise. To access the value you can do so in a `then` calback

```
element(by.css(css + ' input')).getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

You don't mention what you need it for, but note that `expect` can handle promises passed to it, so for a lot of cases you don't need the `then` callback.

```
expect(element(by.css(css + ' input')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual('some-value');
```