# How to get the text which is already present in the input text field using protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" id="username" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="user.fullName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" minlength="3" required="">
```

My code :

```
element(by.model('user.fullName')).getText().then(function(text){console.log(text);})
```

I am not getting any error and everything is showing passed only.

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to getText on an input in protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310442/how-to-gettext-on-an-input-in-protractor)

Comment: @GirishSortur Issue is little different. Here name is saving in ng-model and am not able to get the text. Please see the HTML code.

Comment: Did you try using `getAttribute('value')` instead of `getText()` and see if you still get an error or no value? Also ng-model shouldn't create any problem for you to retrieve the attribute. Probably waiting until angular is settled might help. Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur It worked with little modifications. Thanks