# protractor how to get md-total value

Tags: protractor

I need to get 86 from here. It is total products count now so it is changing for any page

```
<md-table-pagination class="no-border md-table-pagination ng-isolate-scope" md-label="" md-boundary-links="true" md-on-paginate="vm.paginate" md-total="86" md-page="vm.pagination.page" md-limit="vm.pagination.size" md-limit-options="vm.pagination.options" md-page-select=""><!-- ngIf: $pagination.showPageSelect() --><div class="page-select ng-scope" ng-if="$pagination.showPageSelect()">
  <div class="label ng-binding">Page:</div>


<div class="buttons">
  <div class="label ng-binding">1 - 25 of 86</div>
```

Those two are no showing for same place but probably they get value from same place. total products are 86 because.

on page, it is only showing  0-25 - 86 like this. 25 is for one page , size. 86 is total products for that momemnt. I need total products count.

codeelementor shows those for that

```
by.css('.no-border.md-table-pagination')
:
"1"
by.css('md-table-pagination.no-border.md-table-pagination')
:
"1"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-boundary-links="true"]')
:
"2"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-label=""]')
:
"2"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-limit-options="vm.pagination.options"]')
:
"2"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-limit="vm.pagination.size"]')
:
"2"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-on-paginate="vm.paginate"]')
:
"2"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-page-select=""]')
:
"2"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-page="vm.pagination.page"]')
:
"2"
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-total="86"]')
:
"2"
```

the only thing is

```
by.css('md-table-pagination[md-total="86"]')
```

but it doesnot give 86.

Here some answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20387156/6804200

but

```
element.getAttribute('value')
```

i couldnot implement this to

```
element.all(by.css('md-table-pagination[md-total="86"]'))
```

this.

```
 element.getAttribute(by.css('md-table-pagination[md-total="86"]'))
```

but i need 86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using getAttribute incorrectly. Please see the [official documentation here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) for correct usage. You need to pass the name of the attribute to the Element Finder object

```
element(by.css('.md-table-pagination')).getAttribute('md-total').then(function _getAttribute(value){
//The attribute value is available to you here
console.log(value)
})
```

Comment: why doesnot it work with                 'console.log("xqqx",element(by.css('.md-table-pagination')).getAttribute('md-total'));' codeelemontor shows 86 for element(by.css('.md-table-pagination')).getAttribute('md-total')

Comment: console.log() doesnt work because getAtrribute() returns a promise and the value is returned only on resolving the promise