# grab embedded angular ace-editor text in angular using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, ace-editor

I am able to clear and send text to the g-ace-editor element as follows:

```
elm.clear().then(function() {
  elm.sendKeys(text); or element.getAttribute('value')
});
```

However if I need to validate that text is written or sendKeys worked fine, I tried grabbing the text on this element using getText() or element.getAttribute('value') promise, which returns empty string. And so does sendKeys promise return value (empty). Any suggestion how this text value not attached to DOM (thanks to ace-editor lib embed) can be accessed/grabbed?

Html:

```
<g-ace-editor initial-content="editor.initContent" editor-
mode="editor.mode" editor-commands="editor.commands" editor-
id="editor.elementId" on-update="editor.updateContent" class="max-
height max-width ng-isolate-scope"><div ng-attr-id="
{{$ctrl.editorId}}" class="max-height max-width ace_editor ace-dawn" 
ng-style="" id="xxxxx"><div style="position: absolute;"></div>
<textarea class="ace_text-input" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" 
autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" style="opacity: 0; height: 
16px; width: 7.20125px; left: 210.428px; top: 80px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to getText on an input in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310442/how-to-gettext-on-an-input-in-protractor)

Comment: no its not... element.getAttribute('value') returns empty string as well. Note the content of text area or g-ace-editor is not part of the DOM and is hidden. See the html.