# How do I assert the value of an input field with chai/chai-smoothie?

Tags: protractor, chai, cucumberjs, serenity-js

Thanks for chai-smoothie!

How do I assert the value of an input field with chai/chai-smoothie?

Given that getText() is always empty, and we should use element.getAttribute('value') (see: [How to getText on an input in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310442/how-to-gettext-on-an-input-in-protractor))

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
expect(this.nameTextbox).to.eventually.have.value('name');
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
expect(this.nameTextbox.getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.equal('name');

AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal 'name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chai-smoothie` is enable the error message more read friendly when assertion failed. But it can't handle promise: `this.nameTextbox.getAttribute('value')` return a promise.

**Note**: All Protractor API return promise.

You need to use `chai-as-promised` with `chai` to handle promise.

```
var chai = require('chai'),

chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
chai.use(require('chai-smoothie'));

global.expect = chai.expect;

// then can do assertion as following:
expect(this.nameTextbox.getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.equal('name');
```

Comment: Can I use both chai-as-promised and chai-smoothie? How would I configure that?

Comment: Yes, see my updated example code. But pay attention to the version compatible of the 3 packages.